# What is the right bottom bracket for english thread/68mm

Tags: bottom-bracket

I want to buy this group set:

http://www.ribblecycles.co.uk/campagnolo-veloce-silver-10-speed-double-groupset/?currency=USD&location=USA&gclid=CjwKEAiAjcDBBRCJxouz9fWHynwSJADaJg9BvbBLTW4dNo1N01VlEhiZaPi9nROtIuW9MJF7RvMFjBoC1APw_wcB#pid=30008

Not sure which bottom bracket I should pick.

My frame spec says bottom bracket shell is 68mm English thread.

help!

Answer (score 2):

The first one, "Campagnolo Power Torque Outboard Cups (EPS Compatible) Eng". The other ones are for Italian, the other threaded standard still in use, and the various press fit standards.

Comment: ok, ordering!  Will post how it goes.